# Python - pegar valores do csv em certas condições

Tags: html, python, json, csv

Sou novo em python e estou tentando pegar informações de um CSV e passar para JSON.

O CSV é desse formato:

```
QTD    Produto          Estoque_Limitado    
20      pipoca               1      
19      refrigerante         1       
21      doces                0
```

"Estoque_limitado" seria um booleano, então se tem no estoque estaria 1, caso estiver 0 precisaria repor

A dúvida é a seguinte, como pego do csv dessa forma dinamica?

o json está assim:

```
{
"indisponivel":{
"produto": "doces",
"quantidade": 21,
"Estoque": "Reposição necessária"
    }
}
```

Estou pegando pelo python o nome do produto e a quantidade já, mas preciso dessa condição para pegar sobre o estoque

Pyhton:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = pd.read_csv(r"monitoramento.csv", sep=";")

#Trazendo dados fixos

produto=data['Produto']
quantidade = data['QTD']
```

todos produtos que estivessem com 0, precisaria entrar para o json e haveriam mais produtos que esses 3 que citei.

Quem puder ajudar, agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com uma compreensão de dicionário isso fica simples de fazer, usando a função `zip` para iterar sobre as colunas lado a lado e checando sempre se a coluna `'Estoque_Limitado'` possui valor zero:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"monitoramento.csv", sep=";")

produto = data['Produto']
quantidade = data['QTD']
estoque = data['Estoque_Limitado']

resultado = {
    'indisponivel': [{
        'produto': pd, 
        'quantidade': qt, 
        'Estoque': 'Reposição necessária'
        } 
    for pd, qt, es in zip(produto, quantidade, estoque) if es == 0
    ]
}

print(resultado)
```

Output (note que o objeto associado à chave `'indisponivel'` é um array de objetos, uma vez que pode haver múltiplos objetos indisponíveis):

```
{
    'indisponivel': [{
        'produto': 'doces',
        'quantidade': 21,
        'Estoque': 'Reposição necessária'
    }]
}
```

Tentei manter a mesma lógica do seu código, mas note que pode ser custoso iterar sobre todas as linhas do seu CSV durante a compreensão de dicionário.

Se isso for um problema, filtre a tabela original (p.ex. usando `loc`) antes de fazer a compreensão de dicionário (aí também não precisamos usar a condicional dentro da compreensão, pois os valores já foram selecionados):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"monitoramento.csv", sep=";")

filtered = data.loc[data['Estoque_Limitado'] == 0]
produto = filtered['Produto']
quantidade = filtered['QTD']

resultado = {
    'indisponivel': [{
        'produto': pd, 
        'quantidade': qt, 
        'Estoque': 'Reposição necessária'
        } 
    for pd, qt in zip(produto, quantidade)
    ]
}

print(resultado)
```

O output gerado é o mesmo de antes.

Comment: Consegui puxar os dados dessa forma, muito obrigado! ajudou bastante